# Stray end of tag head

Tags: html

I am trying to learn to use framesets in HTML. So, I started a little website with a friend.
In following page (index.html) i receive an error on line 13: "Stray end of head tag". Why I get this error?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Metal's page</title>

        <frameset cols = "20%,*" frameborder = "0">
            <frame src = "pages/menu.html">
            <frameset rows = "10%,*" frameborder = "0">
                <frame src = "pages/title.html">
                <frame name = "main" src = "index.html">
            </frameset>
        </frameset>
    </head> 

    <body bgcolor = red>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <p>Hello, my name is Mihai, but one of my best friend call me "Metal". This is our web page. Enjoy!</p>
        <br/><br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Website address: metalblog.besaba.com 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t actually get that error message with that document, unless you manually tell the validator to ignore the DOCTYPE and use HTML 4.01 Frameset instead.

If you do that, or if you change the DOCTYPE to HTML 4.01 Frameset DOCTYPE, you get the error “ end tag for element "HEAD" which is not open” because the `<frameset ...>` implicitly closes the `head` element, so you are not allowed to close it again.

The reason for the implicit closing is that in a [Frameset document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html), the `frameset` element appears *instead of* the `body` element, after the `head` element. There is no `body` element, since the contents of the frames are all that is displayed.

The following document validates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" 
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Metal's page</title>
    </head> 
        <frameset cols = "20%,*">
            <frame src = "pages/menu.html">
            <frameset rows = "10%,*">
                <frame src = "pages/title.html">
                <frame name = "main" src = "index.html">
            </frameset>
        </frameset>
</html>
```

Note that I have removed the `frameborder` attributes. They are not valid in HTML 4.01 (or in any other HTML version). If you want to remove the borders between frames, you have to use that attribute and accept that the document is not valid. At least there was no way to remove the borders a few seasons ago, when frames were still used by some, though so last season; I don’t think there has been any change in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you have put your frame set inside of the head tags and not the body tags. All content should go in the body.

Comment: i am followind a tutorial that say i need to put frames in head

Comment: Can you link us to the tutorial please?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using a Strict DOCTYPE, which does not permit framesets. Change to a frameset DOCTYPE. Run your markup through [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/) until you are error free.

Comment: changed to: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd"> , but same problem